# javascript file not calling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm writing .HTML code and in this i am calling on .js file names as chart_buttons.js

HTML code:

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
<title>
  Chart
</title>
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart_buttons.js"></script> 
  </head>
<body ng-controller="Channels">
 <p>Set:
     <label ng-repeat="n in [0,1]">
   <input type="radio" name="pageSet" ng-value="n"/>{{n}}
     </label>
 </p>
 <p>Page: 
     <label ng-repeat="n in [0,1,2,3]">
     <input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="$parent.pageNumber" ng-value="n" /> {{n}}
     </label>
 </p>
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="channel in channels | limitTo: groupSize * ((groupSize * pageSet) + pageNumber + 1) | limitTo: -groupSize">
    <p>{{channel.id}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

my java scrip code

chart_buttons.js

```
function Channels($scope) {
alert("hiiii");
$scope.groupSize = 4;
$scope.pageSet = 0;
$scope.pageNumber = 0;
$scope.channels = [
    {"id": "Ch-001"}, {"id": "Ch-002"}, {"id": "Ch-003"}, {"id": "Ch-004"},
    {"id": "Ch-005"}, {"id": "Ch-006"}, {"id": "Ch-007"}, {"id": "Ch-008"},
    {"id": "Ch-009"}, {"id": "Ch-010"}, {"id": "Ch-011"}, {"id": "Ch-012"},
    {"id": "Ch-013"}, {"id": "Ch-014"}, {"id": "Ch-015"}, {"id": "Ch-016"},
    {"id": "Ch-017"}, {"id": "Ch-018"}, {"id": "Ch-019"}, {"id": "Ch-020"},
    {"id": "Ch-021"}, {"id": "Ch-022"}, {"id": "Ch-023"}, {"id": "Ch-024"},
    {"id": "Ch-025"}, {"id": "Ch-026"}, {"id": "Ch-027"}, {"id": "Ch-028"},
    {"id": "Ch-029"}, {"id": "Ch-030"}, {"id": "Ch-031"}, {"id": "Ch-032"}
];
}
angular.module('app', []).controller('Channels', Channels);
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

but when i execute the code it not showing asy output...
so i aded alert in the .js file but it not showing the alert also. so can any one guide me where i went wrong in coding please

Comment: Move alert outside from function (or better, leave only alert). And is there any errors in console?

Comment: have you included the angular js file because i don't see any in your html

Comment: No i didn't added any angular js file. is it need to add. because i don't have the link.

Comment: yes i deleted the alert but also it not showing any output. and no error it showing

Comment: just now i added 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>

but also it not showing output

Comment: is there any thing wrong in code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to put the scripts at the end of your html or wrap your function in a document ready function

Comment: Why wrap function to docready? And there is no difference if function is in header or footer, it can still be called

Comment: Thank you so much i added $(document).ready(). it going to .js file but it not showing any output. can u please check y it not showing output

Comment: @Justinas it makes a huge different if you put it in the head or in the bottom, if you are not using a doc ready function. If you put it in the bottom, the files are called AFTER the content is loaded. So if you are manipulating content and you are putting it in the head section, you will get an error(when not using doc.ready)

Comment: @user2099759 can you tell me what exactly works now and what does not?

Comment: Present it going into the chart_buttons.js file, so the alert is working now. but it not loading the values. it need to load the channels values.

Comment: it not loading values at all.